# Mysql join query on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables and in those tables these basic fields

**contacts**

- con_id (primary key)
- con_name
- con_work_id
- con_country_id

**work**

- work_id (primary key)
- work_company_name
- work_country_id

**country**

- country_id (primary key)
- country_name

I'm trying to run a query which displays the con_name, work_company_name and then the country name for BOTH the contact and the work company.

I've tried this;

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts
LEFT JOIN work ON contacts.con_work_id = work.work_id
LEFT JOIN country ON contacts.con_country_id = country.country_id
LEFT JOIN country ON work.work_country_id = country.country_id
```

But of course this doesn't work because the last join causes a clash with the second one.
I'm almost there, but can't get the query to display the country_name associated with both the contact AND the work company.

I'd appreciate a way forward.

Many thanks,

Wonder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts
LEFT JOIN work ON contacts.con_work_id = work.work_id
LEFT JOIN country c1 ON contacts.con_country_id = c1.country_id
LEFT JOIN country c2 ON work.work_country_id = c2.country_id
```

The trick is to add an alias to the table, so that it is possible to distinguish the two.